# how to run imagemagik commands in PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick

i am trying to bend text using imagemagik in PHP. but the commands shown in the website are not working.

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/texteffect/index.php

how can i run these scripts in PHP ? somebody please help me..

NB :-t \'SOME ARCHBOTTOM TEXT\' -s outline -e arch-bottom -d 1.0 -f Arial -p 48 -c skyblue -b white -o black -l 1 -u lightpink

Comment: this syntax is sensitive... it need proper format's like "",'' etc..

Answer (score 0):

Translate them to the [PHP ImageMagick API](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)

Answer (score 0):

dear you can use exec or passthru command to run image magic commands in php, no need of any API, just installed the latest imagemagick, if you are searching on php.net site the you will det the message like "Not documented"..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using magickwand? I had a similar problem, I didn't have my PHP installation properly configured to use Imagemagick. This link helped

http://www.ioncannon.net/php/75/how-to-compile-imagemagick-for-php-by-hand/