# how can i run imagemagick commands in php?

Tags: php, imagemagick

i am in need of curving a text and place it over another image. i got the below mentioned code from their website and its not working; somebody please tell me how can i do this in php. My system will support imagemagick and its enabled..

convert ( newmug1.jpg -thumbnail 200x200 -write mpr:image +delete ) \
( -pointsize 20 -fill red -background none  label:"Cottenham horse show" -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 120 -write mpr:arc +delete ) \
mpr:image mpr:arc -gravity north -composite combined.jpg

please help me

thanks and regards

tismon

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873306/how-to-run-imagemagik-commands-in-php

Comment: There is an ImageMagick extension for PHP.  See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for more details.

Comment: did you get the correct answer?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `exec` command - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
exec('convert ( newmug1.jpg -thumbnail 200x200 -write mpr:image +delete ) \ ( -pointsize 20 -fill red -background none label:"Cottenham horse show" -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 120 -write mpr:arc +delete ) \ mpr:image mpr:arc -gravity north -composite combined.jpg');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but its not working for me. i had changed "exec" to "system"; but this too failed.

this is the code i had used

<?php

system("convert ( newmug1.jpg -thumbnail 200x200 -write mpr:image +delete ) \ ( -pointsize 20 -fill red -background none label:'Cottenham horse show' -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 120 -write mpr:arc +delete ) \ mpr:image mpr:arc -gravity north -composite combined.jpg");


?>

Comment: wrap the command arounf inverted commas ' rather that quotation makrs " as you have a " in the command

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
exec("<full path to binary> '-dNOPAUSE' '-sDEVICE=jpeg' '-r<resolution>'
     '-g<dimensions' '-dUseCIEColor' '-dTextAlphaBits=4' '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4'
     '-o<where you want the image stored>' '-dJPEGQ=<quality - I used 90>'
     '<pdf file to resize>'", $outputArray);
```

If the placeholders are filled in using variables, the variables, like `$resolution`, just go straight in to the command, like `-r$resolution`.

You might also find this [website](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) helpful.